# Result of TThread execution

Tags: multithreading, delphi

This code seems not to be a proper way to get the result of a thread, even though the form is not freezing, and I can perform different other tasks, maybe another requests, so the number of threads will not equal one all the time, it may be up to 5 requests simultaneously, but not depending on each other.

How this should be done in a "good" manner?

```
function TEApi.FApiRequest(Request: string) : string;
var
  RequestThread : TApiSecureRequest; {TThread}
begin
  RequestThread := TApiSecureRequest.Create(Self, Request);
  while(NOT RequestThread.Terminated) do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  Result := RequestThread.FResponse;
  RequestThread.Free;
end;

procedure TApiSecureRequest.Execute;
begin
  {do some HTTP requests, which is freezing the Mainform without threading}
  FResponse = Result_of_execution;
  Terminate;
end;
```

Comment: You're totally defeating the point of creating a thread in the first place. If you're going to block `TEApi.FApiRequest` at `while(NOT RequestThread.Terminated) do`, there's no point in creating the thread. Just do the work where you are. The point of a thread is to create & start it, then let it do its job while doing other things _at the same time_.

Comment: @CraigYoung, yea, I've understood that. Point of creating thread in my case was the long working `TIDHTTP.Post` request, which was freezing the form without any possibility to put there an `Application.ProcessMessages` line, so I've created a thread only to have my form working, while request is beeing processed. You can read my last comment to _Marko Paunovic_ answer to see a workaround I've invented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DO NOT use `Application.ProcessMessages`. It is example of bad code design, and you should avoid using it.

Instead, use thread callbacks or messages. Example:

**uAPISecureRequestThread.pas**

```
unit uAPISecureRequestThread;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TApiSecureRequestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FResponse: String;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;

    property Response: String read FResponse;
  end;

implementation

constructor TApiSecureRequestThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(TRUE);
  FreeOnTerminate := TRUE; // automatically free thread on terminate
end;

procedure TApiSecureRequestThread.Execute;
begin
  // do the work here and assign result to FResponse
end;

end.
```

**uMainForm.pas**

```
unit uMainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    btCreateThread: TButton;
    procedure btCreateThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure ASRThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  uApiSecureRequestThread;

procedure TfrmMain.btCreateThreadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  asr_thread: TApiSecureRequestThread;
begin
  asr_thread := TApiSecureRequestThread.Create;
  try
    asr_thread.OnTerminate := ASRThreadTerminate;
    asr_thread.Start;
  except
    asr_thread.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ASRThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
var
  asr_thread: TApiSecureRequestThread;
begin
  asr_thread := Sender as TApiSecureRequestThread;

  // process asr_thread.Response here
end;

end.
```

Comment: There is no way to do this in one function, right?
I've thought about that, calling back a function, when thread exits. But this will lead to a massive amount of code in callback handlers, such as _what did that thread_,_why did user wanted that_,_what should we do with the response_.. I mean, there is no straightforward link between request and response. And a user, who will try to implement this API driver must care of all that callbacks in his form... anyway all this leads to the first question of this comment.

Comment: The one that I know about, no. You can check `OmniThreadLibrary` or some other thread libraries, but I'm not sure if there is some mechanism to do this in single function call. It beats the thread purpose.

Comment: Your `syncDone` method is already implemented in `TThread`. It's the `OnTerminate` event and its method is called through `Synchronize` in the `TThread.DoTerminate` method. So, all you can do is just bind the `OnTerminate` event to a form method of the same prototype (it's also `TNotifyEvent` type).

Comment: Omni has `Async` construct which can be useful - http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/07/asyncawait-in-delphi.html , but it cannot be viewed as equivalent of C# 4.5 Async/Await construct.

Comment: That exception swallower is dubious

Comment: Why so? If, .Start() fails for any reason, memory will be always released.

Comment: @Goover: if you want to use a thread and still only have 1 function that waits for the result, then don't use a thread at all. But if you must, then at least change your wait loop to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` instead. That will tell you not only when the thread has terminated, but also when to call `Application.ProcessMessages()`.

Comment: Your call of `Start` won't fail since it does effectively nothing because you're creating not suspended thread (parameterless constructor overload). So a bigger risk is that constructor now...

Comment: @MarkoPaunovic Exception swallowers are always dangerous. In this case, I click the button expecting it to start a job - but something goes wrong - only your program doesn't tell me anything, so I sit waiting for a job to complete that never successfully started in the first place.  The `try..except` itself if fine, but you need to re-raise the exception.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, will it freeze a form? I can check it myself later on, but will apreciate if you just tell me.
@all, I've decided to make secure requests with a simple function, without any threads, and all other requests (get new server statuses) with a repeating thread, which is updating info in TEApi Class, and user can access corresponding fields to know, if it is updated. So, the problem left - is the freezing of the Mainform, when I'm making a secureRequest. So, if `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` will do the job - I'll use it. Anyway, this answer has helped me to set up a background thread.